# TypeError: Object of type ObjectId is not JSON serializable en json.dumps(response).encode('utf-8')

Tags: python, json, mongodb, diccionarios

Intento hacer un servidor que conecte una base de datos de mongoDB con python, y si funciona la conexíon, es una bd de una librería, y siempre que llamo a los libros no tengo problema, y en la funcion encargada de obtener los libros devuelvo un diccionarío, de la siguiente manera:

```
books = {}
for book in self.books.find():
    books[book['id']] = book
return {'status': 'OK', 'message': 'Libros', 'data': books}
```

Con el ciclo for agrego los documentos a un diccionaríoque cre y lo envio, luego en el metodo post imprimo el resultado para asegurarme de que los datos se envian correctamente

```py
response = mongo.get_books()
print(response)
```

Y hasta ahi todo bien, obtengo un resultado como

```
{'status': 'OK', 'message': 'Libros', 'data': {'B0001': {'_id': ObjectId('618436dced84b1182ce7c552'), 'id': 'B0001', 'title': 'El ingenioso caballero Don Quijote de la Mancha', 'argument': 'El ingenioso hidalgo don Quijote de la Mancha narra las aventuras de Alonso Quijano, un hidalgo pobre que de tanto leer novelas de caballería acaba enloqueciendo y creyendo ser un caballero andante, nombrándose a sí mismo como don Quijote de la Mancha.', 'tags': 'Parodia, Sátira, Farsa, Novela psicológica', 'author': 'Miguel de Cervantes', 'lan': 'esES', 'date': '16/01/1605'}, 'B0002': {'_id': ObjectId('6184377bed84b1182ce7c554'), 'id': 'B0002', 'title': 'Romeo y Julieta', 'argument': 'En Verona, dos jóvenes enamorados, de dos familias enemigas, son víctimas de una situación de odio y violencia que ni desean ni pueden remediar. En una de esas tardes de verano en que el calor «inflama la sangre», Romeo, recién casado en secreto con su amada Julieta, mata al primo de ésta.', 'tags': 'Tragedia', 'author': 'William Shakespeare', 'lan': 'esES, enUS', 'date': '1597'}}}
```

Para simplificarlo algo como esto:

```
{'status': 'OK', 
'message': 'Libros', 
'data': 
    {'1': 
        {'id':'xxx', 
        'title':'xxxx'}, 
    '2': 
        {'id':'xxx',
        'title':'xxxx'}
    }
}
```

El problema es cuando lo envio:

```py
self.send_response(200)
self.end_headers()
self.wfile.write(json.dumps(response).encode('utf-8'))
```

A la página web no me envia nada y en la termina me imprime lo siguiente:

```
Exception occurred during processing of request from ('127.0.0.1', 59448)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\elias\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\socketserver.py", line 316, in _handle_request_noblock
    self.process_request(request, client_address)
  File "C:\Users\elias\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\socketserver.py", line 347, in process_request
    self.finish_request(request, client_address)
  File "C:\Users\elias\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\socketserver.py", line 360, in finish_request
    self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)
  File "C:\Users\elias\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\http\server.py", line 653, in __init__
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\elias\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\socketserver.py", line 720, in __init__
    self.handle()
  File "C:\Users\elias\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\http\server.py", line 427, in handle
    self.handle_one_request()
  File "C:\Users\elias\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\http\server.py", line 415, in handle_one_request
    method()
  File "c:\Users\elias\Documents\Python\Programacion_Computacional_III\server.py", line 143, in do_POST
    self.wfile.write(json.dumps(response).encode('utf-8'))
  File "C:\Users\elias\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\json\__init__.py", line 231, in dumps
    return _default_encoder.encode(obj)
  File "C:\Users\elias\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\json\encoder.py", line 199, in encode
    chunks = self.iterencode(o, _one_shot=True)
  File "C:\Users\elias\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\json\encoder.py", line 257, in iterencode
    return _iterencode(o, 0)
  File "C:\Users\elias\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\json\encoder.py", line 179, in default
    raise TypeError(f'Object of type {o.__class__.__name__} '
TypeError: Object of type ObjectId is not JSON serializable
```

Intenté retornar dos datos en la funcion que consigue los libros y solo enviar `response[1]` y siempre me arroja el mismo error

Tengo python 9.0, no creo que eso afecte pero por si acaso, si necesitan más datos para encontrar el error decirmelo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El problema salta pues cada documento en `self.books.find()` contiene el atributo `'_id'` que es una [instancia de `ObjectId`](https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/bson/objectid.html) el cual no es serializable por `json.dumps(...)` (no sabe como pasarlo a `string`).

Es por eso que te convendría convertir manualmente el atributo `'_id'` usando `str()`

Intenta con esto:

```py
books = {}
for book in self.books.find():
    books[book['id']] = book
    # Reemplazamos el valor del atributo '_id' por su valor en string
    books[book['id']]['_id'] = str(book['_id'])
return {'status': 'OK', 'message': 'Libros', 'data': books}
```

Comment: O si, eso era, muchas gracias @Japsz